# How to wait until a Listen mode link gets connected to?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

Suppose we create a link like this:

```
link = LinkCreate["mylink", LinkMode -> Listen]
```

How can we wait until this link gets connected to by another process, and time out if there's no incoming connection?

Comment: **What I'm really looking for is confirmation that the answer below is correct!**

Comment: [Related W Community thread](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/279110?p_p_auth=qPS7Ppwq).

Comment: I can absolutely certify that the answer is correct (although incomplete...there is no timeout that I'm aware of).  I'll add a bit more technical detail to the Community thread, where you ask slightly different questions and make a misleading assertion. But the answer as I now see it here is correct without qualification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkActivate` can be used for this.  This Mathematica function is not documented, however the [C version](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/c/MLActivate.html) is.

From *kernel 1*, do

```
link = LinkCreate["mylink", LinkMode -> Listen]

LinkActivate[link] (* this will block and wait for an incoming connection *)
```

Now from *kernel 2* (or another program, if using the C API), do

```
link = LinkConnect["mylink"]

LinkActivate[link] 
(* will return immediately; at this point LinkActivate in kernel 1 also returns *)
```